# How to get IDF Vector with text2vec

Tags: r, text2vec

is it possible to extract not just the transformed TF-IDF Term-Document Matrix, but also the IDF vector that was used for this transformation with the latest version of text2vec (0.5.1)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it with:

```
model$.__enclos_env__$private$idf
```

**But it is not part of public API** (can be easily changed/removed in future without any notification).

I would like to emphasize - this API **should not be used in practice**. Please use `model$transform()` method instead.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I have one more question: The result is a term-term matrix. I'm looking for the IDF values per term (so a vector), as described here (https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/inverse-document-frequency-1.html), which is almost the same formula that is presented in the documentation. Are the IDF values per term the diagonal values of this matrix? And is the ordering the same than the ordering of the columns of the TDM created with create_tdm() ? Thanks and best regards!

Comment: yes, this is diagonal matrix and idf values on diagonal match the order of document-term matrix. So to transform original `dtm` matrix we just make it rows to have unit l1/l2 norm and multiply it by diagonal idf matrix.